# zend undefined URL handling

Tags: zend-framework, url-routing

hello I am working in Zend. I want to know some thing about undefined URL handling. I have a url like `http://localhost/concierge/login` and it has the following rule in url rule file.

`'admin/login'                  =>array('login',                                array('module'=>'admin','controller' => 'index','action' => 'login'),array(),'login'),`. It all works fine.

But if if change the url like `http://localhost/concierge/lgin` which I have not defined it goes to a blank page where an empty array is shown and there is written `Page not Found`. IT looks bad. I want to know if user writes any thing wrong in url, My application should show `404 error`.

Now I want to know How can I achieve my task? Will I have to define an other rule for url rules files to handle all these errors? If so how this url rule will look like? And for controllers what should I do? Any help ?

Comment: Check http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html, search for `404` on that page (no direct link available). Basically you can drop in the error handler plugin to handle 404s

Comment: Direct link - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler.fourohfour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this using the preDispatch hook of a front controller plugin.

public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) { 
        $disp = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();

```
    if ( !$disp->isDispatchable($request) ) { 
            $request->setModuleName('default'); 
            $request->setControllerName('error'); 
            $request->setActionName('error404'); 
    }
```

}

if the thing doesn't exist (  /registerxxx   instead of /register  for 
example ) then they get bounced to a 404 page.  It has worked so far for me.